# cURL Unsupported SSL Protocol

Tags: php, ssl, curl, tls1.2

I have a cURL request that fails when running it through my PHP 5.4.48 app. Funny thing is, it executes correctly when running it directly through the console, or through Postman.

The API I'm connecting to expects a TLSv1.2 connection, which I am specifying in my app.

Here's my simple request as it is in my PHP app:

```
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, 'https://dev-dataconnect.givex.com:50104');
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS,$payload);

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1 );
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array('Content-Type: text/plain;charset=UTF-8')); 
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSLVERSION, 6);
// curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSLVERSION, 'CURL_SSLVERSION_TLSv1_2'); // specifying value by name was of no help
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_CIPHER_LIST, 'TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA256');

curl_exec($ch);
```

A raw cURL request would look like this (note this fires successfully from within the console)

```
curl 'https://dev-dataconnect.givex.com:50104/' -H 'Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate' -H 'Accept-Language: en-US,en;q=0.8' -H 'User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_10_5) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/47.0.2526.111 Safari/537.36' -H 'Content-Type: text/plain;charset=UTF-8' -H 'Accept: */*' -H 'Cache-Control: no-cache' -H 'Connection: keep-alive' --data-binary $'{"method":"dc_909","id":"confidential","jsonrpc":"2.0","params":["en","confidential","29530","confidential"]}\n' --compressed
```

Also note I didn't need to specify the SSL Version for a successful handshake

Here's the printout from running curl -v 'https://dev-dataconnect.givex.com:50104/'

```
* Connected to dev-dataconnect.givex.com (72.15.49.106) port 50104 (#0)
* TLS 1.2 connection using TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA256
* Server certificate: *.givex.com
* Server certificate: Trustwave Organization Validation SHA256 CA, Level 1
* Server certificate: SecureTrust CA
> GET / HTTP/1.1
> Host: dev-dataconnect.givex.com:50104
> User-Agent: curl/7.43.0
> Accept: */*
```

I'm running

```
 - PHP 5.4.48
 - curl 7.43.0 (within both my MAMP and my Mac environments)
 - OpenSSL/0.9.8zd (within both my MAMP and my Mac environments)
```

I've been troubleshooting this issue since last week. Any ideas???

Comment: is similar question? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21612132/unsupported-protocol-using-curl-in-c

Comment: Thanks but not the same issue. That poster was attempting to make HTTPS cURL requests without having a cURL installation that supported HTTPS.

Comment: what is expected result?

Comment: I'm expecting a JSON response generated from the API's server. Any response from the API's server would preferable. RIght now, all I'm getting is an error message from my own cURL instance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> - OpenSSL/0.9.8zd (within both my MAMP and my Mac environments)
>
> ...
>
> The API I'm connecting to expects a TLSv1.2 connection, which I am specifying in my app.

OpenSSL 0.9.8 has no support for TLS 1.2. Support was only added with OpenSSL 1.0.1.

Comment: how did you solved the issue? same problem Im going thr'

Answer (score 2):

I stumbled on this error today, but on a different flavor. An old site is using TLSv1.0 and since upgrading to Ubuntu 20.04 we couldn't access it. The fix is

```
 curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_CIPHER_LIST, 'DEFAULT@SECLEVEL=1');
```

Comment: This is the correct way! Thanks!!

Answer (score 0):

The following code works for me:

```
<?php
$curl = curl_init();

curl_setopt_array($curl, array(
  CURLOPT_PORT => "50104",
  CURLOPT_URL => "https://dev-dataconnect.givex.com:50104/",
  CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => true,
  CURLOPT_ENCODING => "",
  CURLOPT_MAXREDIRS => 10,
  CURLOPT_TIMEOUT => 30,
  CURLOPT_HTTP_VERSION => CURL_HTTP_VERSION_1_1,
  CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST => "POST",
  CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS => "{\"method\":\"dc_909\",\"id\":\"confidential\",\"jsonrpc\":\"2.0\",\"params\":[\"en\",\"confidential\",\"29530\",\"confidential\"]}",
  CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER => array(
    "accept: */*",
    "accept-encoding: gzip, deflate",
    "accept-language: en-US,en;q=0.8",
    "cache-control: no-cache",
    "connection: keep-alive",
    "content-type: text/plain;charset=UTF-8",
    "user-agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_10_5) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/47.0.2526.111 Safari/537.36"
  ),
));

$response = curl_exec($curl);
$err = curl_error($curl);

curl_close($curl);

if ($err) {
    echo "cURL Error #:" . $err;
} else {
    echo $response;
}
?>
```

Comment: This uses version 1.1, not 1.2 as specified in the question.

Answer (score 0):

Step 1: Open your `phpinfo()`

Step 2: Goto `cUrl` section

Step 3: Check `SSL` is enabled or not. If not you will face the `Unsupported SSL Protocol` error.

Solution :

Try to enable SSL in your MAMP or Install latest version of MAMP

[image]