# Can not compile c++ program with libcurl library

Tags: c++, libcurl

I am using compiler MinGW64 and Clion developer.

What I have done:

1) downloaded curl-7.64.0.tar.gz from 'https://curl.haxx.se/download.html'

2) compiled library via cmd-->curl-7.64.0 root-->'mingw32-make make'

3) after successful make I put headers in include folder of my MinGW, libcurl.a andlibcurldll.a in lib folder of my MinGW.

4) then I tried simple libcurl code with CMake set up in Clion like this:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.12)
add_executable(test main.cpp)
target_link_libraries(test libcurl.a libcurldll.a)
```

and my main.cpp code like this:

```
#include <curl/curl.h>
#include <string>

int main()
{
    auto curl = curl_easy_init();
}
```

And when I compile it I get error 'Process finished with exit code -1073741515 (0xC0000135)'.

Can someone tell where could be a problem?

Comment: @Gox, I tryied to compile program from project folder via 'g++ main.cpp -lcurl -lcurldll' and it seems to be okey with compiling, but I got error during execution now 'curl_easy_perform() failed: Unsupported protocol'

Comment: I added it to my answer.

Comment: and check this for the other issue: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21612132/unsupported-protocol-using-curl-in-c

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to put `-lcurl` in mingw argument list.

Have you done this:

> Make sure that MinGW32's bin dir is in the search path, for example:
>
> ```
> set PATH=c:\mingw32\bin;%PATH%
> ```
>
> then run mingw32-make mingw32 in the root dir. There are other make targets available to build libcurl with more features, use:
>
> ```
> mingw32-make mingw32-zlib to build with Zlib support;
> mingw32-make mingw32-ssl-zlib to build with SSL and Zlib enabled;
> mingw32-make mingw32-ssh2-ssl-zlib to build with SSH2, SSL, Zlib;
> mingw32-make mingw32-ssh2-ssl-sspi-zlib to build with SSH2, SSL, Zlib and SSPI support.
> ```
>
> If you have any problems linking libraries or finding header files, be sure to verify that the provided "Makefile.m32" files use the proper paths, and adjust as necessary. It is also possible to override these paths with environment variables, for example:
>
> ```
> set ZLIB_PATH=c:\zlib-1.2.8
> set OPENSSL_PATH=c:\openssl-1.0.2c
> set LIBSSH2_PATH=c:\libssh2-1.6.0
> ```
>
> It is also possible to build with other LDAP SDKs than MS LDAP; currently it is possible to build with native Win32 OpenLDAP, or with the Novell CLDAP SDK. If you want to use these you need to set these vars:
>
> ```
> set LDAP_SDK=c:\openldap
> set USE_LDAP_OPENLDAP=1
> ```
>
> or for using the Novell SDK:
>
> ```
> set USE_LDAP_NOVELL=1
> ```
>
> If you want to enable LDAPS support then set LDAPS=1

https://curl.haxx.se/docs/install.html